# Почему при клике на текст не меняется его фон?

Tags: javascript

```
  let Ad2 = document.querySelectorAll('.d');
  for (i = 0; i < Ad2.length; i++) {
   Ad2[i].onclick = function () {
    Ad2.style.backgroundColor = "red";
};
 };
```

Comment: .js:52 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined
    at HTMLParagraphElement.Ad2.<computed>.onclick d выводит эта ошибка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы вешаете клик на `Ad2[i]`, а фон меняете у `Ad2`. Указывайте через `this` изменение фона:

```js
let Ad2 = document.querySelectorAll('.d');
  for (i = 0; i < Ad2.length; i++) {
     Ad2[i].onclick = function () {
       this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    };
 };
```

```html
<button class="d">1</button>
<button class="d">2</button>
```

Comment: К сожалению, через `Ad2[i]` работать не будет.

Comment: @DmitriiSedov `for( let i = 0; i < ...` — благодаря let, будет работать)